# how to count bits using INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have 1 field Participation that have a return type as a bit, in my database i would like to sum all the bits and make a new column. at the moment it  works but i am getting wrong data.

```
SELECT ID, Participation......,SUM(CASE WHEN NoOfParticipation = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
AS NoOfParticipation1, SUM(CASE WHEN NoOfParticipation = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
AS NoOfParticipation0 from table1 INNER JOIN table2 on ID=ID 
group by ID, Participation ......;
```

These are the records in my database:

```
    ID||Participation  
    1   0                                   
    1   0              
    1   0
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
ID||Participation||NoOfParticipation1 ||NoOfParticipation0
 1   0              0                    3
```

But currently I am getting:

```
   ID||Participation||NoOfParticipation1 ||NoOfParticipation0
   1   0              0                    1 - this should be 3
   . - further down the list i have records with the same ID
   .
   1   0              0                    1
   1   0              0                    1
```

Comment: Your query and the result do not match: The query has columns  field1, field2, field3 ... NoOfParticipation1, NoOfParticipation0, while the result has columns ID, Participation, NoOfParticipation1, NoOfParticipation0

Comment: Can you add some sample data and a query that actually reproduces the problem (the current query can't be right because it has a join `ID = ID` - so either only one table actually has an `ID` column and its a Cartesian join in disguise, or we're missing parts)

Answer (score 0):

When you only want one row per ID you shouldn't group by additional columns:

```
SELECT id, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN participation = 1 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS NoOfParticipation1, 
       Sum(CASE 
            WHEN participation = 0 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS NoOfParticipation0 
FROM   table1 
       INNER JOIN table2 
               ON id = id 
GROUP  BY id
```

Comment: if i have additional fields such as ID, name, sname etc.. how would i make it appear. if i say `SELECT ID, Name, Surname etc... from ... group by ID` i get error saying name is invalid in the selected list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause. if i include name i get same error but this time i get sname.

Comment: I don't know about your actual data and what you're trying to achieve. You might need to add the columns to the GROUP BY, too (if they're from the same table as the grouping ID). Or you put this query in a Derived Table and join back to your details. Or you do the aggregation in a Dervied Table before the join. If your DBMS supports Windowed Aggregate Functions you can also change the SUMs to SUM(...) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) and remove the GROUP BY...

Answer (score 0):

You should not include `Participation` in the `GROUP BY`, instead using an aggregate function like `SUM`, `MAX`, or `MIN` for it. Yo did not state in your question which one you want, I just will use `MAX`:

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(Participation) as Participation,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NoOfParticipation = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NoOfParticipation1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NoOfParticipation = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NoOfParticipation0
 from table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.ID = table2.ID 
group by ID;
```

If you use `ID` and `Participation` in the `group by`, you will get different rows per different `ID` and `Participation` value combination. I understand your question in a way that you want to have one row in the result per `ID`. Hence this must be the only column in the `GROUP BY`, and you must use an aggregation function for all other columns.

Comment: i have updated my question, i maid a mistake NoOfParticipation column should be created by sum function

Comment: @Dip I still do not understand your requirement: You state "I have 3 fields that have a return type as a bit", but in your statement, you access only one: `NoOfParticipation`. There is no table definition in your question. So, what are the other two bit fields? How do they take part in the result calculation? You state "NoOfParticipation column should be created by sum function". What do you mean? What exactly should be summed?

Comment: i think i confused you. ok - there is only one field `Participation ` which has bit as a return. i want to calculate the total number of 1's and 0's. 1's should be calculated and placed into new column called `NoOfParticipation1 ` and all 0's into another column called `NoOfParticipation0 `

Comment: @Dip Thus, if you just omit the line `MAX(Participation) as Participation,` from my statement above, does this deliver what you want?